# Is this an universal proposition?

Tags: logic

Sentences like "Birds can fly" or "The birds can fly" are simple, universal, or indesignate propositions? Must there be the "all" quantifier to make them universal? Is the "the" article sufficient for the sentence to be considered universal? Are the sentences reffering to all and every bird or to birds in general? If a bird which cannot fly is shown, does it turns any of the sentences false?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: This is a(n) (English) language question. There are languages which don't have articles such as "the". Now, once it is translated to the mathematical language, you would likely put the universal quantifier, and will be very precise what you really want to write. E.g. $(\forall x)(B(x)\implies F(x))$

Comment: Using common sense when someone asserts "Birds can fly" he is expressing a general statement (that is false; see chickens)

Answer (score 0):

"Birds can fly" and "The birds can fly" are both universal because we are talking about birds (also, they are the same sentence just with the thrown in front). If we were talking about a single bird, we would not say birds. If we are talking about a feature about a single bird then there would be an apostrophe 's' after bird, meaning bird's (example: bird's feather.)

The main thing that makes "Birds can fly" and "The birds can fly" universal is the $s$ at the end of the word bird meaning more than one bird.

These sentences are referring to all birds I would say.

If a bird is shown to not fly then it breaks the truth value of this. For example: $\forall x (B(x) \to F(x))$ where $B(x)$ is $x$ is a bird, and $F(x)$ is $x$ can fly, we can show that if one bird, $x$, cannot fly then this statement is false. This statement is false because one bird, namely an ostrich, cannot fly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many subtleties here, and I'm afraid there isn't a clear answer.

- "birds can fly" is traditionally interpreted as a universal proposition. It says that every member of a class ("birds") has a property ("can fly").  One way to think about it is that "birds can fly" is short for "all birds can fly," or more precisely "for every bird $b$, $b$ can fly." This requires a kind of disambiguation of the sentence: the sentence is literally saying that the class of birds itself can fly, but we don't consider it to make sense to ask whether the abstract notion of a class has capacity for flight, so we instead try the interpretation where it means every element of the class can fly, which *is* something that makes sense.
- "the birds can fly" is hard to interpret without context.  It might be referring to a specific collection of birds that we previously referred to ("there are birds around the pond. the birds can fly.").  If it's somehow a stand-alone sentence, it could mean "there exists a bird, and all birds can fly."  It could also mean "all birds can fly."  If you are able to, the correct thing to do is to ask whoever said "the birds can fly" exactly what they meant by that.

> Are the sentences referring to all and every bird or to birds in general?

When it comes to pure logic, these are the same concept.

That said, I think what you're getting at is how we think about kinds of things.  With the way we think about kinds in natural language, it's not a contradiction to say "birds can fly" and then talk about flightless birds -- flightless birds have all the properties of birds except for flight.

I found [this whitepaper](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150FP/archive/graham-nelson/WhitePaper.pdf) by Graham Nelson to be interesting, where he discusses the design of a programming language called Inform 7 for creating text adventure games (a.k.a. interactive fiction) that itself looks like natural language.  It also goes into how to take a textual description of a world and create a minimal model implementing it, which involves carefully interpreting language as logical statements.  He mentions how Anna Wierzbicka's work gives a way to deal with seemingly contradictory kinds like flightless birds.  I think the upshot is that "birds can fly" as a statement ends up being false, because there are flightless birds, but now "birds can generally fly" is true because "generally" would mean birds without any modification, assuming we've defined birds to have capacity for flight.